# Run a single test in loop in Robot Framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a csv file containing the test-data as follows:

```
# Case, StartTime, EndTime, ExpectedResult
Case_1, 2018-01-11T00:10:00, 2018-01-11T00:58:00, 2.5
Case_2, 2018-01-11T00:15:00, 2018-01-11T00:54:00, 3.2
Case_3, 2018-01-11T00:18:00, 2018-01-11T00:47:00, 4.5
...
```

Using robot framework I have added a keyword to read the file's content as follows:

```
Read Data File
    ${LIST}=  Process Data File  session_data.csv    
    : FOR    ${LINE}    IN    @{LIST}
        \    Log    ${LINE}
        \    @{COLUMNS}=    Split String    ${LINE}    separator=,
        \    ${TESTCASE}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    0
        \    Log    ${TESTCASE}
```

I have created a test "Verify Result" to process data from CSV and verify the expected result, but all the process is considered as only one test-case.

For every single row in the CSV file I need to create a single test-case for example as follows:

```
Verify Result for Case_1
Verify Result for Case_3
Verify Result for Case_3
and so on...
```

Please provide suggestion on how to run a single test in a loop in Robot Framework.

Comment: You cannot chunk a single keyword into many single test cases. You'll have to do many test cases. Further reading - [Test templates](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates).

Comment: Depending on how badly you wanted to get this working... you could do what I did to convert TEARDOWN to a keyword (so it doesn't fail a suite). Post Process the html file and convert the keywords into test cases in the html and use `rebot` to regenerate the log files

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want to do can't be done. Robot isn't designed to treat test data in an external file as separate test cases.

What you can do instead is write a script that reads your .csv file and converts it to a series of robot test cases before you run the test. Then, you can run this generated test suite.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Psytho , Test Template could be a solution for your question .

Here is a basic example to give u a direction

```
*** Settings ***

*** Test Cases ***
Look for All Possible Outputs from the System Under Test
    [Template]    Look for Specific Output
   csv1     #These rows are treated as arguments for test cases with [Template]
   csv2     # You can put your list variable as well, i have not checked with list
   csv3

*** Keywords ***
Look For Specific Output
    [Arguments]    ${output}
    Comment    Pretending to look for a specific output...
    Log    ${output}   #
```

Test case would be run three times.

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of RF allow you to [use loop with templates](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#templates-with-for-loops):

```
Verify Result
    [Setup]       Process Data File  session_data.csv
    [Template]    testcase
    FOR    ${LINE}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${LINE}
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert your testcase into a keyword and run it inside a loop in your test case. values can be changed by taking input from CSV with every run

Comment: This still would be a single test case for the whole csv-file, not a single test case for a single line.